# How to put text over ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, android-xml

Currently I have a grid layout filled with images, but I want to display some text on them and the text will change/update over time. What would be the best option?

XML code looks something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="11"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="700dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="CLOSE CONNECTION" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_svgimg_img"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_svgimg_img"/>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use a `FrameLayout`. Try something like this

```
<FrameLayout>
  <ImageView />
  <TextView />
</FrameLayout>
```

The FrameLayout will overlap views, you can play with gravity to adjust positioning. If you need a more complex alignment you can go with more complex layouts like RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout which includes both TextView and ImageView as per your design and use the custom layout in your xml files and and write some methods to update programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you gridView items separately, use those items inside your gridView and with constraintLayout you can put your text on your image like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="I am the text over the image"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]